# How to get git repo from url

Tags: git, bash

I have repo `git@gitlab.com:alex93ushakov-mail/test.git`.

In Bash, I'd like to write a function which takes the git url as an argument and returns the repository name 'test'. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function foo() {
  local a="$1"          # copy first argument to local variable a
  a="${a##*/}"          # strip left part including /
  echo "${a%.git*}"     # strip trailing .git
}

foo "git@gitlab.com:alex93ushakov-mail/test.git"
```

Output:

```
test
```

To avoid trailing newline: add option `-n` to `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex:

```
s/.+\/(\w+)\\\.git/$+/
```

Not sure if bash is equivalent to perl, which I normally use, but this would work.